# Sencha Touch and Cordova App stuck on Startup when running on device

Tags: javascript, cordova, sencha-touch-2, phonegap-plugins, sencha-touch-2.1

I am making a Sencha Touch 2 and Cordova app for Android.
The code is running perfectly well in the browser when I build the code for Android the App starts and is stuck at the Loading Screen.

I traced the problem to this line:

```
Ext.Viewport.getWindowWidth()
```

When I remove this line from my .js files the App works perfectly on my Android device as a native application.
If I add this line the app stops at the loading screen without giving any form of error / crash message. (but works on my mac's browser)

What could be going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds almost as if Ext.Viewport has not yet been rendered when getWindowWidth attempts to resolve. Perhaps try listening to the viewport 'ready' event when the dom is definitely available and you can get the window's width - check out the docs [here](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Viewport-event-ready)